# Имеет ли смысл выделять память под объект Mat в куче?

Tags: c++, opencv, обработка-изображений

Добрый день.
Только начинаю работать с библиотекой opencv, в связи с чем возник вопрос:
Лучше объявлять указатели Mat или же сами объекты?т.е.:

```
Mat* a = new Mat();
```

или же

```
Mat a = Mat();
```

На первый взгляд, кажется что выделение памяти в куче разумней, так как объекты в целом немаленькие, в ходе работы мы можем увеличить размер матрицы и возникнет угроза переполнения стека.
С другой стороны, в тех примерах кода, что я видел, нигде не было использования оператора `new`, да и я нашел следующее утверждение:

> При его использовании (класса Mat) вы освобождаете себя от забот по управлению
>   памятью: выделению и освобождению. Класс реализует счетчик ссылок и
>   память освобождается только тогда, когда она больше не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Те большие объемы данных, о которых Вы пишете, Mat и так выделяет в куче сам. И реализует логику по управлению этой памятью, включая копирование с подсчетом ссылок. Поэтому о переполнении стека беспокоиться ни к чему. Если вам не нужно именно динамическое создание - смело создавайте на стеке.